# Plugin class name must be defined in config property [akka.persistence.snaphot-store.local.class]

Tags: akka-persistence

I'm new to akka and try to learn akka following the video tutorials [here](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-akka-video).

The author has explained the code but didn't explain anything about configuration at all.

My actor code is

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.persistence.{PersistentActor, SnapshotOffer}
import Counter._

object Counter {

  sealed trait Operation {
    val count: Int
  }

  case class Increment(override val count: Int) extends Operation
  case class Decrement(override val count: Int) extends Operation

  case class Cmd(op: Operation)
  case class Event(op: Operation)

  case class State(count: Int)
}


class Counter extends PersistentActor with ActorLogging {

  println(s"Starting...")

  var state: State = State(0)

  def updateState(evt: Event): Unit = {
    evt.op match {
      case Increment(count) =>
        state = State(state.count + count)
      case Decrement(count) =>
        state = State(state.count - count)
    }
  }

  override def receiveRecover: Receive = {
    case evt: Event =>
      updateState(evt)
    case SnapshotOffer(_, snaphot: State) =>
      state = snaphot
  }

  override def receiveCommand: Receive = {
    case cmd @ Cmd(op) =>
       println(s"counter received command $op")
       persist(Event(op)) { evt =>
         updateState(evt)
       }
    case "print" =>
      println(s"current state of the counter is $state")
  }

  override def persistenceId: String = "counter-example"
}
```

My src/resources/reference.conf is

```
akka.persistence.journal.plugin="akka.persistence.journal.leveldb"
akka.persistence.snapshot-store.plugin="akka.persistence.snaphot-store.local"
akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.dir="target/sample/leveldb"
akka.persistence.snaphot-store.local.dir="target/sample/snapshots"
akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.native=off
#akka.persistence.snaphot-store.local.class=
```

My main class is

```
val system = ActorSystem("persistent")
val persistentActor = system.actorOf(Props[Counter], "counter")

persistentActor ! Increment(3)
persistentActor ! Increment(5)
persistentActor ! Decrement(2)

persistentActor ! "print"

Thread.sleep(5000L)

system.terminate()
```

When I execute the main class, I'm encountering the below error -

```
[ERROR] [01/13/2018 20:53:13.961] [persistent-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://persistent/user/counter] Plugin class name must be defined in config property [akka.persistence.snaphot-store.local.class]
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: akka://persistent/user/counter: exception during creation
    at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:193)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:608)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:462)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:484)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin class name must be defined in config property [akka.persistence.snaphot-store.local.class]
    at akka.persistence.Persistence.akka$persistence$Persistence$$createPlugin(Persistence.scala:296)
```

I understand I need to configure the property `akka.persistence.snaphot-store.local.class` in reference.conf, but I'm not sure of the value.

The full code is in [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/LearningAkkaSalmaK/tree/master/chapter4/src/main/scala/persistent/actor).

Also, please help me if some more configuration is needed for this program other than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your configuration is that there is a typo (repeated two times) `snaphot-store` instead of `snapshot-store`. And you don't need to set a customized value for `akka.persistence.snaphot-store.local.class`.

Here's the correct configuration:

```
akka.persistence.journal.plugin="akka.persistence.journal.leveldb"
akka.persistence.snapshot-store.plugin="akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local"
akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.dir="target/sample/leveldb"
akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local.dir="target/sample/snapshots"
akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.native=off
```

Comment: Looks like error message from akka has typo and your suggestion has solved it.